# How to enable only TLSv1.2 in Apache Airflow

Tags: airflow

How to enable TLSv1.2 only in Apache Airflow Service. As per organization security policies require using TLSv1.2 for connections supporting SSL/TLS traffic. I couldn't find anything in the documentation suggesting that it's possible to configure the underlying SSL protocol used by secure connections and Disable the 3DES suite ciphers (SWEET 32 vulnerability). please share the document that would help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set environment variable for Gunicorn (Airflow uses Gunicorn for webserver):

For **TLS 1.2**:

```
GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS="--ssl-version=5"
```

If you want to change ciphers too, you can add them in the above environment variable.

Example:

```
GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS="--ssl-version=5 --ciphers=TLSv1.2"
```

Docs: https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html

We used `--ciphers=EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:DHE+RSA+AES` in one of our projects.

Comment: after enabling the TLS1.2 version in airflow webserver, still iam seeing the 3DES cipher warning and broken RC4. Here is the nmap result. TLS_KRB5_WITH_IDEA_CBC_SHA - unknown
| TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - unknown
| TLS_KRB5_WITH_IDEA_CBC_MD5 - unknown
| TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5 - unknown | TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_SHA - unknown
| TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 - unknownwarnings: 
| 64-bit block cipher 3DES vulnerable to SWEET32 attack
| 64-bit block cipher IDEA vulnerable to SWEET32 attack
| Broken cipher RC4 is deprecated by RFC 7465
| Ciphersuite uses MD5 for message integrity

Comment: @DebiprasannaMallia You can also change the ciphers by adding them in the environment variable `GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS="--ssl-version=5 --ciphers=EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:DHE+RSA+AES"`

Comment: these are list of ciphers received as part of request. The command you have shared does not working. TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - strong|TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - strong|TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - strong|TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA - broken| TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA - strong|TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - broken|TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - broken|TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - broken|TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_NULL_SHA - broken|TLS_ECDH_anon_WITH_RC4_128_SHA - broken|TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_MD5 - strong|TLS_KRB5_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA-strong

Comment: TLS_KRB5_WITH_IDEA_CBC_SHA - weak
|TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 - strong|TLS_KRB5_WITH_RC4_128_SHA - strong|TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA - strong|TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA - strong|TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA - strong|TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA - strong|TLS_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA - strong|TLS_RSA_WITH_IDEA_CBC_SHA - weak|TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_MD5 - broken|TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA - broken
|TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 - strong|TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA - strong|TLS_RSA_WITH_SEED_CBC_SHA - strong

Comment: I mean I was giving you an example. Change the ciphers you want to use in that environment variable. https://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/settings.html#ciphers

Comment: Thanks Kaxil. I figured it out the actual value to enable only TLS1.2 and disable 3DES ciphers from airflow. GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS="--ciphers=TLSv1.2"

Comment: can you help me how to disable the ciphers which do not support perfect-forward-secrecy from the following airflow TLS response. TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (secp256r1) TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384 (secp256r1) TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 (rsa 2048) TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (secp256r1)TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (secp256r1)TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256 (rsa 2048)TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 (rsa 2048) TLS_RSA_WITH_NULL_SHA256 (rsa 2048)

Comment: My server seems to be serving up TLS 1.2, but it allows a ton of insecure cipher suites. How can I limit the cipher suites? I tried the --ciphers flag with below configuration: GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS="--ciphers=EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:DHE+RSA+AES", but does not restrict the TLS protocols and restrict the cipher suites. I have been struggling with this for a while now, the below combination does not start up the airflow service. GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS="--ssl-verion=5 --ciphers=EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH:DHE+RSA+AES".    Thanks !

Comment: Correct parameter to enable the TLS1.2 and disable weak cipher in Airflow service    Environment=GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS=--ciphers=TLSv1.2+EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH+TLSv1.2:AES256+EDH+TLSv1.2:DHE+RSA+AES+TLSv1.2

Comment: @DebiprasannaMallia Do we need to restart the airflow webserver after these changes ?

Answer (score -1):

Setting the GUNICORN variable in the environment file of systemd unit service can also be handy.

example for airflow environment file `/opt/airflow/airflow_env`

```html
PATH=/opt/airflow/.local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:$PATH AIRFLOW_HOME=/opt/airflow/airflow 
PYTHONPATH=/opt/rh/rh-python36 
AIRFLOW_GPL_UNIDECODE=yes 
GUNICORN_CMD_ARGS="--ssl-version=5 --ciphers=TLSv1.2"
```

example for systemd unit service, here we are using airflow-webserver unit service created at `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/airflow-webserver.service` :-

```html
[Unit]
Description=Airflow webserver daemon
After=network.target mysqld.service redis.service
Wants=mysqld.service redis.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=/opt/airflow/airflow_env
User=airflow
Group=airflow
Type=simple
PermissionsStartOnly=true
ExecStartPre=/bin/mkdir -p /run/airflow/
ExecStartPre=/bin/chown -R airflow:airflow /run/airflow/
ExecStart=/opt/airflow/.local/bin/airflow webserver --pid /run/airflow/webserver.pid -l /var/log/airflow
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=10s
PrivateTmp=true

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```